# rbind() returning an odd result

Tags: r

This has all the signs of being something that's so trivially stupid that I'll regret asking it in a public forum, but I've now stumped a few people on it so c'est la vie.

I'm running the following block of code, and not getting the result that I expect:

```
zz <- list(a=list('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), b=list('f', 'g', '2', '1'),
           c=list('t', 'w', 'x', '6'))
padMat <- do.call('cbind', zz)
headMat <- matrix(c(colnames(padMat), rep('foo', ncol(padMat))), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
rbind(headMat, padMat)
```

I had expected:

```
a    b    c
foo  foo  foo
a    f    t
b    g    w
c    2    x
d    1    6
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
a    b    c
a    f    t 
b    g    w
c    2    x
d    1    6
NULL NULL NULL
```

It appears that it's filling in the upper part of the rbind by row, and then adding a row of NULL values at the end.

A couple of notes:

- This works AOK as long as headMat is a single row
- To double check, I also got rid of the dimnames for padMat, this wasn't affecting things
- Another thought was that it somehow had to do with the *byrow=TRUE*, but the same behavior happens if you take that out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from the fact that `padMat` is a strange matrix. R reports that is a list of 12 with dimensions:

```
R> str(padMat)
List of 12
 $ : chr "a"
 $ : chr "b"
 $ : chr "c"
 $ : chr "d"
 $ : chr "f"
 $ : chr "g"
 $ : chr "2"
 $ : chr "1"
 $ : chr "t"
 $ : chr "w"
 $ : chr "x"
 $ : chr "6"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

That appears to be the source of the problem, as recasting as a matrix works:

```
R> rbind(headMat, matrix(unlist(padMat), ncol = 3))
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "a"   "b"   "c"  
[2,] "foo" "foo" "foo"
[3,] "a"   "f"   "t"  
[4,] "b"   "g"   "w"  
[5,] "c"   "2"   "x"  
[6,] "d"   "1"   "6"
```

Answer (score 9):

`padMat` is a list (with a dim attribute), not what you usually think of as a matrix.

```
> padMat <- do.call('cbind', zz)
> str(padMat)
List of 12
 $ : chr "a"
 $ : chr "b"
 $ : chr "c"
 $ : chr "d"
 $ : chr "f"
 $ : chr "g"
 $ : chr "2"
 $ : chr "1"
 $ : chr "t"
 $ : chr "w"
 $ : chr "x"
 $ : chr "6"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

I suspect you want something like:

```
> padMat <- do.call(cbind,lapply(zz,c,recursive=TRUE))
> str(padMat)
 chr [1:4, 1:3] "a" "b" "c" "d" "f" "g" "2" "1" "t" "w" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

The lesson here is, "`str` is your friend." :)

Comment: Oops, keep hitting enter and not shift-enter.  class(padMat) returns 'matrix'

Comment: Ah right (and I see you just updated the same thing).  is.matrix is TRUE but so is is.list.  Interesting.  I'd never encountered that (knowingly) before.

Comment: @geoffjentry read `?is.matrix` and note that `is.matrix()` returns TRUE if applied to a vector which has a dim attribute. A list is a vector and your list has a dim attribute. Hence the report. But look at `str(padMat)`...

Comment: Right, I see now. just saw in ?cbind that you can have a matrix of lists, didn't realize that.

Comment: @geoffjentry: see @Gavin's comment. :)  I'll edit that `padMat` is a list (which is a vector) with a dim attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Others have correctly pointed out the fact that `padMat` had mode `list`, which if you look at the docs for rbind and cbind, is bad:

```
In the default method, all the vectors/matrices must be atomic (see vector) or lists.
```

That's why the `do.call` works, since the elements of `zz` are themselves lists. If you change the definition of `zz` to the following:

```
zz <- list(a=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), b=c('f', 'g', '2', '1'),
       c=c('t', 'w', 'x', '6'))
```

the code works as expected.

More insight can be had, I think, from this nugget also in the docs for rbind and cbind:

```
The type of a matrix result determined from the highest type of any of the inputs 
 in the hierarchy raw < logical < integer < real < complex < character < list .
```

Comment: Right.  In this case the sublists had to be lists, the vals for the example were just simplified for SO.  It also turned out that the whole thing wasn't the right way to go about things, but this particular problem had turned into a brain teaser here at the office